# Static Code Analysis through API

Tags: .net

I am looking for some automated process to achieve code review for JS, & C#

Is there any API available to do same? Basically, I would like certain static coding guidelines to be always followed i.e. Code without comment at Class or Method Level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options that you can go with:

- [nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) - a commercial static analysis tool for .NET (no JS support)
- Use [Visual Studio automation and API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff718165)
- Take a look at the [Roslyn CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx)
- [StyleCop](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) and [FxCop](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6544)

Most of these will help with .NET (C# and VB.NET), but not with JS. For JS you may be able to use [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/), though I don't know how automateable that can be.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [project Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/roslyn). This includes a compiler API, it is still in CTP, but should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

*Oded* quoted the tool NDepend. The new version of NDepend comes with a complete NDepend.API to write your own static analyzer to automatize code reviews.

- [NDepend.API overview](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html)
- [NDepend.API introduction](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API_introduction.html)
- [NDepend.API getting started](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html)

*Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of the tool*

NDepend.API is LINQ friendly. More than [200 code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed. They are based on LINQ queries over NDepend.API, what we call [CQLinq](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) . These code rules cover a wide range of needs (API, evolution/diff, naming, architecture/design, code metric/quality, dead code, code coverage, OOP...) You can adapt them to your own needs and create your own ones to perform automatized **code reviews**.

14 *Power Tools* open source base on NDepend.API are proposed. *Power Tools* are actually custom static analyzers, or in other words, sophisticated programs to automatize **code reviews**. Here also you can adapt them or create your own ones. If you download the NDepend bits, the code source of these *Power Tools* is in the VisualStudio solution: *$NDependInstallPath$\NDepend.PowerTools.SourceCode\NDepend.PowerTools.sln*

[image: NDepend Power Tools List]

Answer (score 0):

Use [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [Stylecop](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) for c#. These two tools can be used to automate the process.

While developing the code in Visual Studio if you want some basic code suggestions then ReSharper is a great tool.